# Is cross validation a general method for evaluating any kind of model?

Tags: cross-validation

**Can I apply CV to models other than those from machine learning or statistical methods such as a biophysical energy balance model?**

k-fold cross-validation is used to evaluate models built by machine learning or statistical methods.
But, I have rarely seen applying the CV to other models such as a process-based biophysical model.

My guess is that I can use the evaluation method for any kinds of model because the CV is to avoid bias in judging model performance from a specific subset of whole data.